# PHP Laravel, How to create a relation with groupBy to handling double data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having a hard time processing data that has multiple ids into one, I think this will require groupBy on the relation.

Table Transaction

| id | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Morning Transaction | 2022-09-29 |
| 2 | Evening Transaction | 2022-09-29 |
| 3 | Night Transaction | 2022-09-29 |

Table Detail Transaction

| id | transaction_id | item_id | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | A |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | B |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | C |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | A |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | B |
| 7 | 3 | 3 | c |

Table Item

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | XXX |
| 2 | YYY |
| 3 | ZZZ |

Transaction Model -> hasMany with detail

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'transactions';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'date',
    ];

    public function detail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Detail::class, 'transaction_id');
    }
}
```

My Table in View

```
<tbody>
    @forelse ($transction as $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->date</td>
            <td>
                @foreach($data->detail->groupBy('item_id') as $list)
                    - {{$list->item->name}}
                @endforeach
            </td>
        </tr>
    @empty
        <tr>
            <td>Data Not Found</td>
        </tr>
    @endforelse
</tbody>
```

Result table what I want:

| Transaction | Date | Detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Morning Transaction | 2022-09-29 | -XXX -YYY |
| Evening Transaction | 2022-09-29 | -ZZZ |
| Night Transaction | 2022-09-29 | -ZZZ |

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are looking for a hasManyThrough relationship? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: I would suggest dropping the Detail model and use the current details table as a pivot table between transaction and items, with grade as extra column. This makes a query for all the items a bit easier. Or is the Detail model needed for other stuff?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the many - many relationship here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many
This will allow you to join the Transaction table to the Item tables using the details as the intermediate, remember to use the ->withPivot() option on the relationship to retrieve the other columns